# Publishing Web App to Azure

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

I have a web app on Azure. When I publish an update to it using WebDeply it doesn't work. I get a 502.5 Process Failure error. Upon investigation the content of the error is:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions, Version=2.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
   at Web.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

Does anyone know why I would be getting this?

It works locally but not when published. The most recent update I did to the AspNetCore ddls was done as part of this release where I upgraded the NuGet packages reference to be the latest patch fixes ie. from 2.0.0 to 2.0.2. Is it something I did wrong?

Comment: Check the "copy local" setting in Visual Studio before you deploy. It might be that the assembly it tries to load in Azure isn't there. Setting "copy local" to true should include the assembly in the installation.

Comment: @kim Thanks. I downloaded the version that is on the server and it shows as version 2.0.2 so I am pretty sure the correct version is on the server. Still no luck with getting this to work unfortunately

Comment: Deleting everything from the target folder indeed did the trick! Thanks

Comment: when possible, its best to use git based publishing or FTP (which you eventually stumbled upon as the solution). web deploy is spotty at best in my experience as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually solved the issue by using an FTP, deleting all of the DLLs in the website folder and re-publishing the application.

Seems Web Publish or VS decided not to update those files for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Addional information for Adam Stapleton.

As Adam Stapleton mentioned it seems that Web publish or VS doesn't update the related files. If we update the AspNetCore, I recommend that we could remove the Azure WebApp files during republish the WebApp. We also could do this with VS. For more detail information, please refer to the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: We have this selected and are publishing via VS 2017 version 15.7.3. We still occasionally run into this issue. Still looking for a 100% fix